# Java Applet not loading after enabling apache SSL

Tags: java, apache, ssl, applet

After enabling SSL and forcing all http requests to redirect to https on my apache server, one of the pages containing a java applet won't load. No errors in java console or in the browser console.
All the other web pages are loading successfully.

Is this an expected behaviour?

p.s. The certificate is self-signed. Just testing functionality here..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

since it is applet, try to find it in applet console rather than web container log. to enable it go to control panel > java > advance > show console. let me know if you find any error there

Comment: As i already stated above, no errors in java console as well.